# Where did my simplification go wrong? Sum and difference formula simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions

I'm struggling with the following: We are to use the sum and difference formulas to find the exact value of the expression. The problem is simplification has been tough. As a last resort I decided to use Symbolab to find the answer and steps but the steps were not to be found. Despite lack of steps, the answer is $(\sqrt {2+\sqrt{3}})/2$

Here are my steps so far:
\begin{align*}
\sin(135^\circ - 30^\circ) & = (\sin 135^\circ\cos 30^\circ)-(\cos 135^\circ \sin 30^\circ)\\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)-\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}\right)-\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)
\end{align*}
[insert final simplification step]
$(\sqrt {2+\sqrt{3}})/2$

What's the missing step here?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, your equations should include equals signs.

Comment: its not an equation. Its an expression.

Comment: When you evaluate the expression $\sin(135^{\circ} - 30^{\circ})$ by setting it equal to $\sin(135^{\circ})\cos(30^{\circ}) - \cos(135^\circ)\sin(30^{\circ})$, you have an equation.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}- \left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right) & = \frac{1}{4}(\sqrt6+\sqrt2)\\
                       & = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(\sqrt{3}+1)\\
                       & = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\sqrt{(\sqrt3+1)^2}\\
                       & = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}\\
                       & = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\\
                       & = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}

Comment: I dont see how you get from one step to the next

Comment: @DiamondLouisXIV edited to simpler form

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, your equations should include equals signs.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks, got it

Answer (score 2):

$x=\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}4$
$====================$
$x^2=\frac{6+2\sqrt{12}+2}{16}=\frac{8+2\sqrt{12}}{16}=\frac{8+4\sqrt3}{16}=\frac{2+\sqrt3}4$
$====================$
$x=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}2$

Comment: The two expressions are equal because they are both *positive* numbers with the same square.