# About the equivalence of $\cos(x) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ and $\cos(x) = \cos(2x-x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

By the title, my questions may sound trivial or silly, but I have problems with those outputs.

I need the sine of $15$ degrees. Now I thought of: $15 = 45-30$ hence:

$$\sin(15) = \sin(45-30) = \sin(45)\cos(30) - \cos(45)\sin(30) = \dfrac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

So far so good.

Yet, when calculating the cosine, I have

**Mode 1**

$$\cos(15) = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(15)} = \sqrt{1 - \dfrac{8 - 4\sqrt{3}}{16}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}$$

**Mode 2**

$$\cos(15) = \cos(45-30) = \cos(45)\cos(30) + \sin(45)\sin(30) = \dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

The second method returns something more clean than the previous one. I did not really see the numerical equivalence though, so I computed the difference and I found that

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2} - \dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} = 1.11\cdot 10^{-16}$$

(On W. Mathematica).

Can someone please explain me this infinitesimal difference between them, and how to pass from Mode 1 to Mode 2 in writing?

Comment: Note that the two real numbers are both greater than 0. Have you tried to compute $(\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2})^2$ and $(\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4})^2$?

Comment: @Asigan Their square is the same. I don't get how to pass from the first "bad" writing to the "simpler" second one.

Comment: So we know that if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $a^2=b^2$, then $a=b$ because $0=a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ and $a+b\neq 0$. I hence think that their square are the same implies they being the same real number.

Comment: Seeing how it's "only" a $10^{-16}$ difference, maybe it's just a rounding error/difference in roundings on the comupter/software part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1651617

Comment: @L.F. Awe, that really helps!

Comment: @BrunoB Perhaps you're right, a rounding error from a software indeed!

Comment: It's definitely a rounding error. 1.11e-16 is the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) ($2^{-53}$ in double precision). For two different formulas that theoretically yield the same number, it's not unusual to get slightly different values (and sometimes not so slightly).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you so much for this, I didn't know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{8+4\sqrt{3}}}{4}
$$
Solving
$$
8+4\sqrt{3} = (a+b\sqrt{3})^2
$$
results in
$$
\begin{cases}
 a^2+3b^2=8 \\
 ab = 2
\end{cases}
$$
and solving that results in
$$
(a, b)= (\sqrt2, \sqrt2), (\sqrt6, \sqrt\frac{2}{3})
$$
so
$$
8+4\sqrt3 = (\sqrt6+\sqrt2)^2
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\sqrt{8+4\sqrt3}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}
$$

So it's probably a rounding error in the software.